# Hashchange causing phonegap app to crash?

Tags: ios, ajax, cordova, hashchange

I'm using ajax within my phonegap app to load the content for different pages. I'm also using the onhashchange to enable back button functionality.

All works fine initially but if I click 3 different links (and trigger 3 hash changes) then my app completely crashes, becomes unresponsive and then eats up all my memory.

The code of the hash change is below, anyone got any ideas why it might be crashing/memory leaking?

```
$('a.ajax').click(function () {
    location.hash = $(this).attr('href').match(/(^.*)\./)[1]
    return false
})

function hashChange() {
    var page = location.hash.slice(1)

    if (page != "" && window.location.hash) {
        wrap.load('pages/' + page + ".html .page-wrapper", function(){
            closeMenu();
        })
    }else{
        wrap.load('pages/Welcome.html .page-wrapper', function(){
            closeMenu();
        })
    }
}

// check for hash change
if ("onhashchange" in window) {
    $(window).on('hashchange', hashChange).trigger('hashchange')
} else { // lame browser
    var lastHash = ''
    setInterval(function () {
        if (lastHash != location.hash)
            hashChange()
        lastHash = location.hash
        //contentScroller.scrollTo(0,0);
    }, 100)
}
```

Just to note, I'm getting the following error within the xCode console and I'm running version 2.9 of phonegap

CDVWebViewDelegate: Navigation started when state=1

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't entirely sure what was causing the crash but I decided to use this plugin http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/ and now everything works fine

```
var wrap = $('#contentScroller .scroller');

$('a.ajax').click(function () {
    location.hash = $(this).attr('href').match(/(^.*)\./)[1];
    return false;
});

$(window).hashchange(function () {
    var page = location.hash.slice(1);

    if (page !== "" && window.location.hash) {
        wrap.load('pages/' + page + ".html .page-wrapper", function () {
            closeMenu();
        });
    } else {
        wrap.load('pages/Welcome.html .page-wrapper', function () {
            closeMenu();
        });
    }
});
```